powershell Get-Acl on Windows Sandbox
a friend was asking how to change the permissions for a registry key. I did not want to test it on my laptop, so i started up the Windows Sandbox on my windows 11 laptop and added that registry key.
But when i executed the command as admin
$acl = Get-Acl HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MyKey

it was returning nothing and $acl was still null.
Then i tried it on another machine, and there it was working as expected.
Is this something by design for the Windows Sandbox? Or did i do something wrong?

Windows Sandbox provides a clean, isolated environment that's reset every time you launch it. This sandbox is designed to prevent permanent changes to your main system, including any modifications to the registry. As a result, the registry inside the Sandbox is separate from the host machine's registry.
